# Equals method of System.Collections.Generic.List<T>...?

Tags: c#, .net, list, equals

I'm creating a class that derives from List...

> `public class MyList : List<MyListItem> {}`

I've overridden Equals of MyListItem...

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    MyListItem li = obj as MyListItem;
    return (ID == li.ID);  // ID is a property of MyListItem
}
```

I would like to have an Equals method in the MyList object too which will compare each item in the list, calling Equals() on each MyListItem object.

It would be nice to simply call...

```
MyList l1 = new MyList() { new MyListItem(1), new MyListItem(2) };
MyList l2 = new MyList() { new MyListItem(1), new MyListItem(2) };

if (l1 == l2)
{
    ...
}
```

...and have the comparisons of the list done by value.

What's the best way...?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the Linq method [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) on the list since your list implements `IEnumerable`. This will verify all the elements are the same and in the same order. If the order may be different, you could sort the lists first.

Here's a minimal example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // for .SequenceEqual

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var l1 = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
        var l2 = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
        var l3 = new List<int>{1, 2, 4};
        Console.WriteLine("l1 == l2? " + l1.SequenceEqual(l2));
        Console.WriteLine("l1 == l3? " + l1.SequenceEqual(l3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        MyList<T> list = obj as MyList<T>;
        if (list == null)
            return false;

        if (list.Count != this.Count)
            return false;

        bool same = true;
        this.ForEach(thisItem =>
        {
            if (same)
            {
                same = (null != list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Equals(thisItem)));
            }
        });

        return same;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a poor solution on a few levels: First, `FirstOrDefault` searches the list from the start, meaning the time complexity is quadratic for what should be an element-by-element comparison. Secondly, `FirstOrDefault` only returns the pairwise element when it's unique; otherwise, you'll get an incorrect comparison for, say, `{1, 2}` and `{1, 1}`. Finally, even if this was correct, it doesn't have the early bailout you'd expect for an equals list method; it keeps iterating even after finding `same` to be false. Use SequenceEquals as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398769/6243352).